# Why did Facebook use Javascript rather than an HTTP Header in this Example?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-headers

I was looking at the example code below from the [developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) outlining OAuth Authentication using PHP.

My question is: **Why did they echo a script to redirect the user, rather than using header("Location") ?**

```
//see link for full code...

if(empty($code)) {
 $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); 
 $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

//see link for full code...
```

Thanks.

Comment: any output before this bit of code?

Comment: do you mean echoing? no.

Comment: then i would say - bad choice by the developer, perhaps you should ask them

Comment: Because the facebook documentation is an incredible mess, I've taken examples directly from their docs that haven't worked at all.

Comment: just because facebook, google, microsoft .. say to do X does not mean its the best way, humans are - very human.

Comment: Perhaps it's because there's a prior call to `session_start()` which outputs cookie info? (I looked at his referenced link.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top.location would indicate breaking out of a iframe, a header location will only affect the immediate containing iframe.

Comment: So does that mean that this code is also flexible towards Canvas Apps? After all, these are contained within iFrames.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler I assume so, especially now that you can also use Page Tab Applications as iframes, but then they also have the "signed_request" functionality http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/